# Proving $\tan(90^\circ- x) = \cot x$

Tags: trigonometry

How do you prove $\tan(90^\circ-x)=\cot x$ using the compound angle formulae?

Comment: What _is_ the compound angle formula that you can use?

Comment: Try drawing triangles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\tan(90^\circ-x)=\frac{\tan 90^\circ-\tan x}{1+\tan 90^\circ \tan x}=\lim_{z\to \infty}\frac{z-\tan x}{1+z \tan x}=\lim_{z \to \infty} \frac{1-\tan x/z}{1/z+\tan x}=\cot x.$$
Note that $\tan 90^\circ=\infty.$

**Alternate way** $$\tan(90^\circ-x)=\frac{\sin(90^\circ-x)}{\cos (90^\circ-x)}=\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}=\cot x$$

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach that avoids infinities and limits:

$$\tan(90^\circ-x)=\tan(45^\circ+(45^\circ-x))=\frac{1+\tan(45^\circ-x)}{1-\tan(45^\circ-x)}=\frac{1+\left(\frac{1-\tan x}{1+\tan x}\right)}{1-\left(\frac{1-\tan x}{1+\tan x}\right)}$$
$$=\frac{2}{2\tan x}=\frac{1}{\tan x}=\cot x$$
as required.